# What does the 'element' term in (dolist (element list) ...) mean?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I've been working through a tutorial on common lisp, and I've just been introduced to `incf` and `dolist` , I wanted to see if I properly understood how dolist functions by making a function `inc-list` that would increment every element of a list by one:

`(defvar a-list (list 1 2 3))`

`(inc-list a-list) => (2 3 4)`

Here is how I defined inc-list

```
(defun inc-list (list)
  (progn 
    (dolist (element list)
      (incf element))
    list))
```

---

This doesn't seem to work. when I try `(inc-list a-list)` I get back `(1 2 3)` and
 `a-list => (1 2 3)`.  This wouldn't bother me as much if it weren't for the fact that doing :

```
(incf (car a-list))
(incf (cadr a-list))
(incf (caddr a-list))
```

gives me `a-list => (2 3 4)`.   Is there some secret to what `element` means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`element` is bound to each of the elements of the list, in turn, i.e. the value of the `car` of each pair is in a sense "copied" to it. Then, `incf` is called on `element`, incrementing *that variable's value*, but *not the list position that it was taken from*. It's as if you're doing

```
(defvar element (car a-list))
(incf element)
(setq element (cadr a-list))
(incf element)
(setq element (caddr a-list))
(incf element)
```

Here too, `element` is incremented and then immediately "forgotten" each time because it's `setq`'d to a new value. By contrast, `(incf (car a-list))` increments the `car` of `a-list` *in-place*. If you want that behavior in a loop, then forget about `dolist` and `loop on` the list instead:

```
(loop for position on lst
      do (incf (car position)))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(defvar a-list (list 1 2 3))
```

**Side note**: Don't write global variables like this. Write `*a-list*`. Otherwise the global dynamic variable influences your local variables.

```
(defun inc-list (list)
  (progn 
    (dolist (element list)
      (incf element))
    list))
```

You don't need `PROGN`. `DEFUN` already allows a sequence of forms, as does `DOLIST`.

```
(defun inc-list (list)
  (dolist (element list)
    (incf element))
  list)
```

Above is sufficient.

`DOLIST` is a form which introduces a new (!) local variable called `ELEMENT`.

`DOLIST` sets the value of `ELEMENT` in each iteration.
All you do is incrementing the value of `ELEMENT` in each iteration step.
 Your side effect is lost. The original LIST is not changed. The value of `ELEMENT` is otherwise not used.